# Can I change combobox value when a button is clicked in java?

Tags: java, jcombobox

By using doClick() method, the action of a button can be triggered. Is there such a way to change combobox value when a button is clicked in java? Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean change the value that is selected or change all the values of the combobox?

Comment: Which graphical framework do you use, AWT, Swing, JavaFX or something else?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't state the graphical framework I assume you use Swing, as it contains a [`doClick` function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29).

The `doClick()` function is only used to emulate a button click programmatically, for example in testing. This will fire all actions that are normally associated with that button, however you need to register those yourself, using a [listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).